# How to get original payload from a Mule Message?

Tags: mule

In the middle of a Mule flow (inside a Class that extends the AbstractTransformer) I need to print (for logging purposes)
as much as possible from the original message (the actual XML that was send trough SOAPUI to MULE)

In order to know how to get the message I'm trying to get the message out of RequestContext.getEvent()
but I haven't been able to find it,
does anyone knows how to do this?

for now I'm trying to find what I need via a deprecated method:

```
RequestContext.getEvent().getMessage().getPayload()
```

But this is not what I need, and this:

```
RequestContext.getEvent().getMessage().getPayloadAsString()
```

doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

By "inside a transformer", do you mean inside the transformMessage() method?

If so, you can log the SOAPUI content with:

```
@Override
public Object transformMessage( MuleMessage message, String outputEncoding )
{
    log.info( message.getPayload() );

    ...the rest of your code here
}
```

Comment: I'm inside an overrided version of a doTransform Method.  protected Object doTransform(Object src, String enc) throws TransformerException { .. }

Comment: 'message.getPayload()' doesn't return a string and thus it can't be logged and RequestContext.getEvent().getMessage().getPayloadAsString() is not working either.. (it doesn't return anything)

Comment: Subclass from AbstractMessage transformer and use transformMessage() as in the example.

Answer (score 0):

If you need access to the `MuleMessage` in a `Transformer`, extend `extended by org.mule.transformer.AbstractMessageTransformer` instead of extending `org.mule.transformer.AbstractTransformer`.

This will give you this method to override:

```
public abstract Object transformMessage(MuleMessage message,
                                    String outputEncoding)
                             throws TransformerException
```

Comment: is therea anything else I could do to access the MuleMessage without changing the AbstractTransformer to AbstractMessageTransformer ??

Comment: I was thinking on overriding the  public MuleEvent process(MuleEvent event){...}

Comment: Don't mess with `process(...)`. The `AbstractMessageTransformer` base class exists exactly for your use case: use it.

Comment: I can't use it because then I can't override the doTransform method.. [Cannot override the final method from AbstractMessageTransformer]

Comment: Re-read my answer carefully: you need to override `transformMessage` not `doTransform`.

Comment: I have a working class that extends AbstractTransformer, I'm already overriding doTransform inside. Trying your solution I changed the class to extend AbstractMessageTransformer instead of AbstractTransformer. then I can override the transformMessage class (to get the originak message), but when I did this Mule complained that 1- doTransform can't be protected anymore (fine), and 2- that [Cannot override the final method from AbstractMessageTransformer] for the doTransform.. so I can't compile it, to see if my newly ovverrided transformMessage class works.

Comment: Your transformation code should be in `transformMessage` not `doTransform`. You shouldn't have a `doTransform` method in your `AbstractMessageTransformer`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31957/discussion-between-david-and-david-dossot)

Answer (score 0):

In onCall method we have eventContext using this

eventContext.getMessage.getPayload we can get payload.

Answer (score 0):

eventContext.getEvent().getMessage().getPayload()
or
eventContext.getEvent().getMessage().getPayloadAsString()